# Android Icon Tutorials

Tags: resource-recommendations, icon, mobile

I've been trying to find tutorial on to make android icons as for the 2.0+/3.0+ specifications. I've found some based on the old 1.x specs but these are quite outdated. Does anyone have anything out there for this?

I'm a developer that is trying to make some Android apps and would like to improve the visual appeal of my products. I've been making all the resources myself with good progress but I'd like to go further.

Comment: here is a [Tutorial for creating an icon for an Android button](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=41) too~ Enjoy it~~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey Check this links might they help you for your icons...

1. [android App Developer Gui icons
   Fonts ETC](http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/)
2. [Free android Icon pack](http://androgeek.com/android-icon-packs-basics-and-a-list-of-free-icon-sets.html)
3. [Free Icons For Android Developers](http://www.bijusubhash.com/blog/free-android-icons-for-developers)
4. [350+ free and fresh icons for android](http://ntt.cc/2010/08/04/350-fresh-and-elegant-free-icons-for-android.html)

---

I don't know you need this or not but i am posting it for every android user .

1. [The easiest way to create android icons (inkscape)](http://envyandroid.com/archives/271/easiest-way-to-create-android-icons)
2. [All  Tutorials for android if you stuck anywhere](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials)
3. [Designing android icon](http://www.cutelittlefactory.com/articles/designing-android-icons/)

Hope this help you a little.....

Comment: Most of the icons on all these sites are duplicates and aren't usable in my apps. The article about the asset studio and inkscape is interesting though. I've seen asset studio before and it looked cool but I didn't realize it was so powerful until the article explained it. Good show.