# GUI .psd for Android HDPI screens

Tags: interface-design

I am working on an android app but I cannot find any UI elements for the high pixel density resolutions, such as the following:

480x800
480x852

Anybody know where I can get this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check these links, might be they will work for you

1. [Psd for android GUI](http://www.matcheck.cz/androidguipsd/)
2. [Android GUI Set free Photoshop
   PSD](http://www.webdesignshock.com/freebies/free-photoshop-android-interface-gui/)
3. [May be this Android question/answer
   help you.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/android-icon-tutorials)
4. [40 Free GUI](http://www.2expertsdesign.com/resources/40-free-web-and-mobile-ui-wireframe-kits-and-resources)
5. [50 Free Web UI, Mobile UI, Wireframe Kits And Source Files For Designers](http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/02/02/50-free-web-ui-mobile-ui-wireframe-kits-and-source-files-for-designers.html)

Hope this will help a bit....